# Java Comparator given the name of the property to compare

Tags: java, compare

My problem is this; I have to order a table of data. Each row of the table is an object (lets call it TableObject) stored in a List. Each column of data is a property of the class (usually a String).

I have to do the typical ordering of data when the user clicks on any column. So I thought about changing the List to a TreeSet and implementing Comparator in my TableObject.

The problem comes when I try to reorder the TreeSet. The compare is fairly easy at first (cheeking for exceptions in parseInt have been omitted):

```
   public int compare(TableObject to1, TableObject to2){
        TableObject t1 = to1;
        TableObject t2 = to2;

        int result = 1;

        if(Integer.parseInt(t1.getId()) == Integer.parseInt(t2.getId())){result=0;}
        if(Integer.parseInt(t1.getId()) < Integer.parseInt(t2.getId())){result=-1;}

        return result;

    }
```

But when I have to reorder by the text of the data or by other dozens of data that the TableObject has I have a problem.
I do not want to create dozens of compare functions, each for one. I prefer not to use a switch (or a chain of ifs) to decide how to compare the object.

Is there any way to do this in some way (like Reflexive), that doesn't imply that I will write like hundreds of lines of nearly the same code?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) should work.

Using reflection the `BeanComparator` that will allow you to sort on any property that has a zero parameter method that returns the value of the property.

So basically you can sort on any property that has a "getter" method.

Comment: Thanks, seems pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is make the comparator take a `String` representing the name of the parameter to sort by in its constructor.

Then you could use reflection to sort by the given parameter.

The following code is very dirty.  But I think it illustrates the gist of what you would need to do.

```
public class FieldComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    String fieldName;

    public FieldComparator(String fieldName){
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        Field toCompare = o1.getClass().getField(fieldName);
        Object v1 = toCompare.get(o1);
        Object v2 = toCompare.get(o2);
        if (v1 instanceof Comparable<?> && v2 instanceof Comparable<?>){
            Comparable c1 = (Comparable)v1;
            Comparable c2 = (Comparable)v2;
            return c1.compareTo(c2);
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Counld not compare by field");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It illustrates it very well. I tryed to do it like that but it's been a few years of any reflexivity program... Again, thanks!

Comment: I would like to vote this as correct, but camickr response, even as is not as work out as yours is easier and faster to implement. I think we should not rewrite code that already works. Even then, I would gladly mark both of them as correct, if I could.

Comment: @Random, no worries.  I'd go with camickr's solution too.

Comment: I just tested this approach to see if accessing the field directly is faster than accessing it through a method. It only worked for me when the field was defined as public. It didn't work for protected or private fields.

Comment: @cam, yeah.  You need to change the code a bit to make it work for private/protected fields.  (minimal changes)

Comment: @jinguy, I found that the getDeclaredField(...) method will work for public and protected. Just curious, how would you do it for private?

Comment: @camick, it works for private as well.  But you also have to call `Field.setAccessible(true)` in order to access the parameter. (Inherited from `AccessibleObject`)

Comment: Two things: (1) Since most fields are private I'm using `getDeclaredField` to select the field. (2) @jinguy, you say the code is dirty. Why? How could it be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use the [reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html), to get the content of a field based on it's name.

See [`Field`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class and especially the [`Field.get`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

(I wouldn't recommend it though, as reflection is not designed for this type of task.)

Comment: "reflection is not designed for this type of task" ... All the more reason to beat it into submission and leave it pleading in the corner to be left alone.

Comment: well... If I have the name of the property I need, then it's a refelction task. Thanks for the Field.get Although my project is in Java 5...

Comment: I disagree. From the very first page in the [Reflection Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) you can read *"Reflection is powerful, but should not be used indiscriminately. If it is possible to perform an operation without using reflection, then it is preferable to avoid using it."*