# Sort a List by more than one attribute

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

- I have some Recipe objects, that contain different attributes like Season,Region,Category (all Strings)
- There is a cookbook, containing a List of Recipes. Also the cookbook has an Attribute sortLevelChain (String).
- sortLevelChain specifies, in which order I want to sort the containing Recipes in List by just connecting the Recipe attribute names with a dot (e.g. "Season.Region.Category").

now i need a solution on how to get the List sorted in the way, that is specified by the sortLevelChain. I found Apaches ComparatorChain, but i've got no clue how to use it. Every working solution is welcome =)

Comment: What are you calling "dynamical sortlevel" ?

Comment: split the string on "." then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135998/java-comparator-given-the-name-of-the-property-to-compare

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is straight forward.Hope the sample below helps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.collections.comparators.ComparatorChain;

public class ComparatorChainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ComparatorChain comparatorChain = new ComparatorChain();
        String[] filters = "Season.Region.Category".split(".");
        Comparator comparator = null;
        for(String filter:filters){

            if("season".equalsIgnoreCase(filter)){
                comparator = new Comparator<Recipe>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Recipe o1, Recipe o2) {
                        return o1.getSeason().compareTo(o2.getSeason());
                    }
                };
            }
            if("region".equalsIgnoreCase(filter)){
                comparator = new Comparator<Recipe>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Recipe o1, Recipe o2) {
                        return o1.getRegion().compareTo(o2.getRegion());
                    }
                };
            }
            if("category".equalsIgnoreCase(filter)){
                comparator = new Comparator<Recipe>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Recipe o1, Recipe o2) {
                        return o1.getCategory().compareTo(o2.getCategory());
                    }
                };
            }
            comparatorChain.addComparator(comparator);
        }
        List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
        Collections.sort(recipes,comparatorChain);
    }

    public class Recipe{
        private String season;
        private String region;
        private String category;
        public String getSeason() {
            return season;
        }
        public void setSeason(String season) {
            this.season = season;
        }
        public String getRegion() {
            return region;
        }
        public void setRegion(String region) {
            this.region = region;
        }
        public String getCategory() {
            return category;
        }
        public void setCategory(String category) {
            this.category = category;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities here. For the Apache `ComparatorChain`, read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). You have to implement a Comparator for each order you wish, here a `SeasonComparator`, `RegionComparator` and a `CategoryComparator`.

For the `ComparatorChain`, instantiate it and add the comparators one after the other:

```
ComparatorChain<Recipe> chain = new ComparatorChain<>();

for (String elt : sortLevelChain.split("\.")) {
    if (elt.equals("Season"))        chain.addComparator(new SeasonComparator());
    else if (elt.equals("Region"))   chain.addComparator(new RegionComparator());
    else if (elt.equals("Category")) chain.addComparator(new CategoryComparator());
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparator not supported");
}

Collections.sort(recipeList, chain);
```

The use is quite simple, but you can optimize this method if you often need this chained Comparator.